# AVPlayerLayer Stopped by Music

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am using an `AVPlayerLayer` to play a video. The video has no sound. However, if a user is playing music in the background and the `AVPlayerLayer` is displayed, the music stops. If the user swipes up and hits play, the video stops.

I have even set the `muted` property of `AVPlayer` to `true` yet this still occurs.

How can I prevent the `AVPlayerLayer` from interfering with any music the user might be playing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video decoding seems to interrupt audio apps and vice versa (I think it can even interrupt *yourself*). You can disable this behaviour by configuring "mix with others" on your audio session:

```
NSError *error;

if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error]) {
    // handle error
}

if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error]) {
    // handle error
}
```

I don't know why, but setting a simple `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` category with no options works too:

```
if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error]) {
    // handle error
}
```

I used to have complicated theories on why `mix-with-others` was necessary and even obvious for this sort of use case, but I've forgotten them and would prefer a pointer to some documentation instead.

p.s. I'm pretty sure both the above solutions will disable remote control events for your app. hope that's ok. once again, would love some doco.